# How to find duplicate record when mysql givesDuplicate entry '10:78:5b:9f:0e:c1' for key 'UK_pttkmqgejqcvdojl6gdkt8wi0' error

Tags: java, mysql

Is there any way to find the duplicate record from the given exception other than hitting MySQL with another where clause.

Exception :

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '10:78:5b:9f:0e:c1' for key 'UK_pttkmqgejqcvdojl6gdkt8wi0'
```

Answer (score 0):

not from the error but you can create a query to see it,

select field name
from tablename
where fieldname = 10:78:5b:9f:0e:c1

and you have to place the name of the column where this 10:78:5b:9f:0e:c1 is stored instead of "field name"

Comment: is there any other way....i dont want to hit another query to find duplicate record

Answer (score -1):

Only, Doing in Java - First Get all records and create map of that data then search record using the key.